# Google search index и google ad

Tags: google-search, google-adsense

У меня 2 вопроса. Я зашел на webmasters там скачал файл,все что сказано было сделал так и не появляется мой сайт на поиске. Я создал sitemap отправил их google. Потом что надо сделать? А по поводу адсенс я открыл аккаунт там добавил свой сайт,создал объявление потом код получил копировал код. А я не вижу свое объявление(2 дня прошло). Как бы 300х300 да например блок объявление, выделено место на сайте вижу разделаются блоки(между div-ами я поставил объявление) но там пусто. Почему это так?

Comment: дайте урл сайта, а то тут можно долго ванговать почему сайт не индексится и реклама не отображается.

Comment: По поводу индексирования - не сразу появляется, до 2 недель может пройти

Comment: www.clickblog.ml (пока что сайт не полный)

Comment: 2 недель? понятно спасибо